# Javascript add a break line after every other number from array

Tags: javascript, html

I have an array that returns some numbers like 222.000,333.000,444.000,555.000. Ideally I want to format so it places a breakline "\n" after every other number. i.e. Would be like

```
222.000,333.000
444.000,555.000
```

Can it be done by modifying the lines below?

```
n107 = parseFloat(output1),
n108 = parseFloat(output2),
n109 = parseFloat(output3),
n110 = parseFloat(output4),
list = [];

 // add values to array if they're not NaN or > 0
if (n1) {
list.push(n1);
}

if (n2) {
list.push(n2);
}
if (n3) {
list.push(n3);
}

if (n4) {
list.push(n4);
}
if (n5) {
list.push(n5);
 }

 if (n6) {
list.push(n6);
}

// combine values into a string separated with commas    
document.getElementById('inputTextToSave').innerHTML = list.join(",");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a optimal solution.but it works

```js
n107 = parseFloat("222.00"),
n108 = parseFloat("333.00"),
n109 = parseFloat("444.000"),
n110 = parseFloat("55.00"),
list = [n107,n108,n109,n110];


// combine values into a string separated with commas    
//document.getElementById('inputTextToSave').innerHTML = list.join("</br>");

var j =1;
var htmlString = '';
for(var i =0; i< list.length; i++){
  
  if(j<2){
   htmlString += list[i]+",";
    j++;
  }else{
    htmlString += list[i]+"</br>";
    j=1;
  }

}
document.getElementById('inputTextToSave').innerHTML = htmlString;
```

```html
<div id="inputTextToSave"></div>
```

Comment: @Alexa is this you wanted?

Comment: I was using the list above because I don't want to print 0zeros or NaN. I'll see if your example will allow me not to print 0zeros or NaN. thx

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your own string in a loop instead of using `join()`.

There are lots of ways to create the loop...the key is to check the index within the loop to determine which separator to use

```js
var list = [222.000,333.000,444.000,555.000];

var res = list.reduce((newStr, currVal, index) =>  
        newStr += (index % 2 ===1 ? ',' :'\n') + currVal ); 
  
document.getElementById('inputTextToSave').innerHTML = res;
```

```html
<pre id="inputTextToSave"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by using [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=control) method.

```js
const list = ['222.000', '333.000', '444.000', '555.000']

const result = list.reduce((memo, item, index) => {
  const comma = (index+1)%2 === 0 ? ',' : ''
  const lineBreak = (index+1)%2 === 0 ? '<br />' : ''
  memo += comma + item + lineBreak
  return memo
}, '')

document.getElementById('inputTextToSave').innerHTML = result;
```

```html
<div id="inputTextToSave"></div>
```

Comment: no need for declaring and incrementing `c` if use third argument of `reduce()` which is index

Answer (score 0):

you can try this function

```
function addBrakes(array){

    let cutPoint = 3 // set where you want to cut
    
    for(i=1; i<=array.length; i++){
        if(i%cutPoint == 0){
            array.splice(i, 0, "<br>")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Another option:

```
document.getElementById('inputTextToSave').innerHTML =    
    list.join(',').replace(/([^,]+,[^,]+),/g, '$1<br>')
```